# Nomenclature in Texshop

Tags: texshop, nomenclature

I have been trying to add Nomenclature to my thesis. I have found that I have to create a Nomenclature.engine and run it so that it would show up in the final file. This file, as per many answers on this website, must be located at /Library/TeXShop/Engines/. Such directory does not exist on my mac. Is there a new way to add nomenclature?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not `/Library/TeXShop` it's `~/Library/TeXShop`. I.e., the `Library` folder in your home directory.

Comment: Yes, I have typed it with the "~" symbol and seemed to follow the instructions. I have found the Nomenclature.engine file in ~\Users (home) directory, and could not find any folder named TeXShop. I am sorry, I am new to this, haven't got a clue what to do.

Comment: What happens when you do the following: In the Finder, type Command-Shift-G. This should open a dialogue box that says Goto Folder. Cut and paste (don't retype) this: `~/Library/TeXShop` into the dialogue box.  What happens?

Comment: Fixed everything. This found the folder, so I moved the .engine file there. Everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TeXShop has the `TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop` command so there's no need to hunt for it.

Why don't you try using the `pdflatexmk` engine since it may already be setup to deal with your nomenclature problem. Just put the line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` at the top of your file and typeset using `Typeset->Typeset` (Cmd-T).

Comment: This is the kind of thing that long-time users like me never notice! Thanks, Herb.